# 50A/240v outdoor into two 20A/110v and one 10A/110v sockets

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a 50-amp 240-volt outlet (previously used for clothes dryers), I want to divide it into three 110v sockets, two 20A/110v, one 10A/110v socket, you can let me know  What materials are used? Thanks for reply!!

Comment: What size breaker actually feeds this outlet? What size wire currently goes to this outlet? Note: 110V is really 120V (1/2 of 240V). 10A sockets are extremely rare for US/Canada which is where you normally have 240V/120V and big dryers, so that sounds strange.

Comment: Starting the question at the wrong end.  It is better to know what you want to plug in and use at same time, that lets you know size of outlets, wire/cable, and size of breaker you need.  Wire on a 50 amp circuit is usually too big to fit into those outlets, but you can add smaller gauge wire to it, if you use a smaller breaker also.

Comment: What does the existing socket look like?  3 holes or 4?  *Don't be tempted to jury-rig this together.  Do it right.*

Comment: Can you post photos of the outlet in question and the inside of the outlet box for that matter?

Comment: How many wires and what colors are available in the dryer socket? You may be able to install a sub but that will require a 4 wire feeder 2 Hot a neutral and a ground.

Answer (score 1):

First red flag is most dryers operate on 240v 30A, not 50A. So you need to confirm the wire is sized appropriately for the breaker feeding the dryer receptacle.

If you have just a 3 wire dryer receptacle then since that wire was installed under a special exception it is likely the wire is not good for any other purpose.

After confirming the compatibility of the number and size of the wire and breaker then unless you mount a sub-panel you can only run two circuits configured as a Multiwire Branch Circuit sharing the neutral. The two circuits can be a two pole breaker if both circuits have similar receptacles, or can be two single pole breakers with the handles tied with approved handle ties. Receptacle sizes that are allowed on breakers can be found doing a search for [Table 210.21(b)(3)](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Table%20210.21(b)(3)&t=vivaldi&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images).  You will have to change the breakers to match the receptacles allowed.

If you mount a subpanel generally you can assume a diversity of loads and connect receptacle circuits that if run concurrently would exceed the rating of the panel.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a [sub-panel](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-100-Amp-6-Space-12-Circuit-Outdoor-Main-Lug-Load-Center-HOM612L100RBCP/100143240) (if possible, pictures  of the location of the current 50A outlet would help) and couple of breaker for all of your receptacles. You need to run #6 wire to your sub-panel, #12 wire (romex would work if inside) to your 20A receptacles and #12 or #14 for your 15A receptacle. For your sub-panel. you need two bus bars (one for natural and one for ground).

Some older homes do not have a ground wire on the dryer recepticle, you need to make sure that you have one running from your main panel.

BTW. you can have more circuits/ receptacles on that sub-panel as long as your barker (at the main panel) is 50A.

Please upload some pictures so we can help you more accurately.